# Naudio ImaAdpcmWaveFormat, BufferedWaveprovider not happy

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am working on an application where I use Naudio to play sound streamed to/from a modem (no luck with tapi on this particular modem, so AT-commands).

This works acceptably well when I used a linear waveformat (WaveFormat waveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);) but now I want to try getting full duplex, which means that using a slightly more efficient sound format is probably a good idea.

Saw that Naudio has an ImaAdpcmWaveFormat, so tried to replace the WaveFormat object with that one (ImaAdpcmWaveFormat imaadpcm_waveformat = new ImaAdpcmWaveFormat(8000, 1, 4);).

However, now the waveout.init throws a System.DivideByZeroException :(.

I had a similar problem when I had managed to misread the specification for WaveFormat and put 2 instead of 16 for "bits", but 4 bits/sample should be an acceptable rate for IMA ADPCM? Anyhow, same exception for 8 or 16 bits/sample...

Exception data:

> System.DivideByZeroException 
>   HResult=0x80020012 
>   Message=Attempted to divide by zer0.
>   Source=NAudio
>   StackTrace:
>     at NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat.ConvertLatencyToByteSize(Int32 milliseconds)
>     at NAudio.Wave.WaveOut.Init(IWaveProvider waveProvider)
>     at USRModemTest.Form1..ctor() in C:\Users\c\Source\Repos\USRModemTest\USRModemTest\Form1.cs:line 56
>     at USRModemTest.Program.Main() in C:\Users\c\Source\Repos\USRModemTest\USRModemTest\Program.cs:line 19

From the constructor:

Note that this works acceptably well if I replace imaadpcm_waveformat with waveFormat

```
//waveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
imaadpcm_waveformat = new ImaAdpcmWaveFormat(8000, 1, 4);

//bwp_ModemToSpeakers = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveFormat);
bwp_ModemToSpeakers = new BufferedWaveProvider(imaadpcm_waveformat);
bwp_ModemToSpeakers.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
//bwp_ModemToSpeakers.BufferDuration = System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
bwp_ModemToSpeakers.ReadFully = true;
bwp_ModemToSpeakers.BufferLength = 1000 ; // as small as possible it seems

waveout = new WaveOut();
waveout.DeviceNumber = -1; // default communications device
waveout.DesiredLatency = 200;
waveout.Init(bwp_ModemToSpeakers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot play audio encoded with IMA ADPCM directly. I recommend you decode the audio into PCM before placing it into `BufferedWaveProvider`. Examples of this can be found in the NAudio demo project and you can make use of the `AcmStream` class for the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will do that :).